# Energy transfer in resistors

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, potential-energy, voltage

The change in electric potential energy $\Delta U$ of a charge $Q$ as it moves from $r_1$ to $r_2$ is given by
$$\Delta U=Q\Delta V,$$
where $\Delta V$ is the potential difference between the two points.

I understand that a battery increases the electric potential energy of charges by doing work on them from high to low potential against the electric field, giving $\Delta U=Q\mathcal{E}>0$.

However, when I try applying this calculation on a resistor of potential drop $\Delta V<0$, I got $\Delta U=Q\Delta V>0$, which is clearly incorrect as the potential energy should \emph{decrease} as it is dissipated as heat at a resistor. Where did I make an error?

Comment: the $\Delta U$ is just the heat energie you get, so it should be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a heuristic Drude-like picture, an electron in a circuit moves from the low potential side of the battery through the circuit to the high potential side of the battery, so when it "moves through a resistor", the change in potential is positive. Thus, the change in potential energy is
$$\Delta U = q\Delta V = (-e)\Delta V<0\,.$$
Thus, the system is losing potential energy (while the kinetic energy stays the same because the system is really in steady-state when there is a constant current flowing), and so that energy has to go somewhere. That energy that is lost is actually transferred into thermal energy in the resistor due to "collisions" between the electron and the ionic cores in the resistor (again, in a simplified Drude-like model of an electron moving through a resistor).